# jQuery - Why is the Ajax() error callback always called?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to return a confirmation JSON object back to my AJAX function. For some reason, even though, the post is successful (200) the error callback function is always called. I am logging the returning JSON to a file for dubgging and it appears correct. I cannot figure out why this is happening. Can someone offer a suggestion?

PHP Controller Action (CI):

```
public function sendMail()
    {
        $senderName = trim($_POST['senderName']);
        $returnEmail = trim($_POST['returnEmail']);
        $message = trim($_POST['message']);


        if (valid_email($returnEmail))
        {
            send_email('email@email.com','Website Email From: '.$senderName, $message);
            $success = array('success'=>'Mail Sent');

            //Debugging to file
            $myFile = "testFile.txt";
            $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
            $stringData = json_encode($success);
            fwrite($fh, $stringData);
            fclose($fh);


            echo json_encode($success);
        }
        else
        {
            $errorMessage = array('error'=>'Invalid Email Address');
            echo json_encode($errorMessage);
        }
    }
```

}

JS:

```
$.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "http://domain.com/index.php/mail/sendmail",
                   data: {senderName: senderName, returnEmail: senderAddr, message: message },
                   dataType: "JSON",
                   success: function(msg){
                     console.log(msg);
                   },
                   error: function(data){
                        alert("Something went wrong"); // possible that JSON wasn't returned
                    }
                 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I was not using a relative url for a target. I believe the issue was a cross domain scripting problem. I changed the url property to index.php/mail/sendmail and all is well.

```
$.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "index.php/mail/sendmail",
               data: {senderName: senderName, returnEmail: senderAddr, message: message },
               dataType: "JSON",
               success: function(msg){
                 console.log(msg);
               },
               error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    var x = xhr;
                    var y = ajaxOptions;
                    var z = thrownError;
                }
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `error` callback takes up to *three* arguments: the XHR object, an error string, and an optional exception object.  Accept the last two as well and they should tell you what's going on.

You may also want to use a debugger like Firebug, Dragonfly, or Chrome's developer tools to see if the request is as successful as you think.

Comment: I use firebug.. and I know the post is working because, in this case, the email is sent. Ill look at the XHR object for hints. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunalty.. the XHR object only shows a statusText = error

Comment: What about `status`, `readyState`, `responseText`?  You could also try stepping through the actual request with Firebug and a development copy of jQuery.

Comment: ReadyState = 0, status = 0, responseText = "" Not very helpful is it.. I supposed I could walk through the jQuery implementation.. was hoping it would not come to that.

Comment: Oh, wait, what did Firebug say about the ajax request?  Receiving the email doesn't necessarily mean the response was right.